# Why <h:dataTable> make all rows as same as "selected row" value?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I've  ArrayList Collection carry the values properly , but the problem when i rendered it in **h:dataTable** tag the rows become all same value like in the picture.

[image]

```
<h:dataTable value="#{contactController.contacts }" var="contact"
            rowClasses="oddRow, evenRow" styleClass="contactTable"
            headerClass="headerTable" columnClasses="normal,centered"
            rendered="#{not empty contactController.contacts }">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    </h:column>

                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText
                    value="#{contactController.contact.firstName }#{ contactController.contact.secondName }" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText value="Action" />
                    </h:column>
                </f:facet>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:commandLink value="remove"
                        action="#{contactController.remove }">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{contact }"
                            target="#{contactController.selectedContact }" /> 
                    </h:commandLink>
                    <h:commandLink value="edit" action="#{contactController.read}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{contact }"
                            target="#{contactController.selectedContact }" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

Any suggestion? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two problems with your code.

First you don't need the bean's name in your columns. Simply use the content of the `var` attribute (in your case "contact" and not "contactController.contact")

Second: The `h:column` inside `f:facet` is not correct. Put the `h:outputText` directly into `f:facet`.

Change your first column this way:

```
<h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="Name" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{contact.firstName} #{contact.secondName }" />
</h:column>
```